# Rによる存在しない項目も含めたcsvファイルの結合

Tags: r, tidyverse

Rを使用しcsvファイルの編集をしています。

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
lf <- list.files(full.names = F, pattern="csv", recursive = FALSE)
data <- data.frame()
 for(i in 1:len(lf)){
   add <- fread(lf[i]) %>% select(ID,hogehoge)
   data <- rbind(data,add)
 }
```

という感じでアンケートデータの結合を行っているのですが、hogehogeのなかの質問項目が途中まではなかったのに何回目からの調査からか質問が導入されたものがありエラーで困っています。
できれば質問されていない回の解答をNAとして統合したいのですがどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。
すべての項目を結合（その回に存在しない項目はNA扱い）してから`select`でもかまわないです。
よろしくお願い致します。

**追記**
`Error in select(., hogehoge) : unused argument (hogehoge)`
のエラーが途中で出ましたが、`dplyr`と`data.table`の`select`が競合しているためのエラーのようです。
`dplyr::select()`とすることで解消しました。
また、上のプログラムについては
http://www.housecat442.com/?p=698
を参考にさせていただきました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rbind()`の代わりに`dplyr`パッケージの`bind_rows()`を用いることで解決できると思います

例

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 7, b = 8, d = 9)

library(dplyr)    
bind_rows(df1, df2)
#    a b  c  d
# 1  1 3  5 NA
# 2  2 4  6 NA
# 3  7 8 NA  9
```

**[EDITED]**
実際の手順としては、以下の様な感じで最初に全て結合させてから`select()`するのがシンプル (＆おそらく高速) です

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

lf <- list.files(full.names = F, pattern="csv", recursive = FALSE)

obj <- lapply(lf, fread) %>%      # リスト形式になるようlapply()で読み込み
  bind_rows() %>%                 # bind_rows()でリスト要素を結合
  select(ID, hoge)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。dplyrパッケージ中の関数なので速度面からいってもこちらのほうが早そうですね。

Comment: @user87562; 解答として不完全だと感じたため、補足を行いました、申し訳ありません。

Comment: 細かいですが、`bind_rows`はリストに対しても使うことができるので`do.call(bind_rows, .)`の部分は`bind_rows(.)`でも大丈夫だと思います。参考までに。

Comment: @yutannihilation; アドバイスありがとうございます、訂正させていただきました。

Comment: @cuttlefish44 ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`data.table`の構文によるこうすれば役に立つとおもいます：

```
library(data.table)
obj = rbindlist(lapply(lf, fread, select = c("ID", "hoge")))
```

なぜあとで除くつもり列を初めに含むか？こうしたらまず除いてから結合する。